# How to post data with AJAX and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have HTML like this:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<p>1</p> <!-- this is loaded with <?php echo $item->id; ?> -->
<a id='delBtn1' my-data='tnt' onlick='del(this)' href='index.php?page=mypage'>
    <img src='del.ico'/>
</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function del(e) {
            var p = $('a< p' ).html();
            $.post('index.php?page=mypage', {
                msg: e.getAttribute('my-data'), 
                id: p
            }, function(data, status) {
                alert("Sent " + data.msg + ' : '+ status);      
            });
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

I don't know why I can't get the the `id` '1' and post to index with a '?' in the URL for data {msg, id}.

Comment: it you want it in the URL as a query string, then you can't use POST. use [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Your code makes no attempts to get an `id`...? Just the `my-data` which is `tnt` and the `html()` which is an `img` element. Assuming you want the text of the `p` element (the only `1` I can see in your code) use `var p = $(e).prev().text()`

Comment: no, i want to get ID in <p> and my-data in <a> then sent to index.php?page=mypage

Comment: You sure isn't a typing mistake?, you have `onlick` attribute instead of `onclick`

Comment: @Forcefield well spotted - I missed that one :)

Comment: `onlick` needs to be added to the spec, I see a lot of good potential use cases for it

Comment: @JeffPuckettII make a proposal to W3C to includeit on  HTML6 sensorial web APIs :)

Comment: yeah i did  type it incorrectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to get ID in `<p>` and my-data in `<a>` then sent to index.php?page=mypage

Firstly what you're calling the `id` is just the innerText of the `p` element. To retrieve that you need to traverse the DOM from the provided `a` element using `prev()` and retrieve it.

Also note that `my-data` is not a valid attribute for an `a` element. To store custom data with an element you should use `data-*` attributes. You should also use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your events instead of clunky and outdated `on*` event attributes.

With that said, the following should work for you:

```
<p>1</p>
<a id="delBtn1" class="delBtn" data-my-data="tnt" href="index.php?page=mypage">
    <img src="del.ico" />
</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal link behaviour 
        var $el = $(this);

        $.post($el.attr('href'), {
            msg: $el.data('my-data'),
            id: $el.prev('p').text(),
        }, function(data, status) {
            alert("Sent " + data.msg + ' : '+ status);      
        });
    });
});
```

Finally you state that you want the request data to be put in the URL, if that's the case you should use `$.get` instead of `$.post`.

Comment: some how,it's really work with me. Of course, i did eidt a bit for my project. Thank for helping and give me advice.